# How do I detect Change in Observable?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, observable

Say I have IObservable and I want an observable that ignores the repeating numbers of the original one, how can I do that ? I tried the following

I have tried GroupBy() but it is a hot observable,  which is not going to work. And all I need to compare with is with the previous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`DistinctUntilChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229494(v=vs.103).aspx).

```
// yields 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3
IObservable<int> a = ...;

// yields 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3
IObservable<int> b = obs.DistinctUntilChanged();
```